# Angular radio button not binding

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I am trying to bind radio button using Angular binding. but it's not working properly. When I am add the data to database, binding is working. Then I edit this added items, binding working, then I change the radio button, and not saved, ie, click cancel. Again I edit the same item , the value of radio button become wrong.

```
<input type="radio" name="radio_select" value="false" ng-model="IsEndDate" ng-change='EndDateChange(IsEndDate)' disable-valid-styling="true">Never
 <input type="radio" name="radio_select" value="true" ng-model="IsEndDate" ng-change='EndDateChange(IsEndDate)' disable-valid-styling="true">On
```

my codes,

```
      if (schedule.RepeatModel.EndDate) {
            $scope.IsEndDate = 'true';
            ........................
            ........................
        }
        else {
            $scope.IsEndDate = 'false';
          ..........................
          ..........................
        }
```

Comment: try by giving true/false values without quotes.

Comment: @ Shrey Kejriwal not working